# Pass a String from one Activity to another Activity on AndroidStudio

Tags: java, string, android-studio, android-intent

This is a newbie on Java, so I'm not sure if the question is suitable or not. I 'll try to describe my issue as simple as I can.

I work on a project with various Activities and methods. My aim is just to **pass** a local variable(String) from one Activity (**MultiboxTracker** -- the one that contains the desired variable) to another (**CameraActivity** -- the one that want to pass the variable).

**The MultiboxTracker's structure:**

```
public class MultiBoxTracker extends AppCompatActivity {
...
  public synchronized void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
  ...
  (Here is the wanted String variable!)

  }
}
```

**The CameraActivity's structure:**

```
public abstract class CameraActivity<labelID, title> extends AppCompatActivity
                      implements OnImageAvailableListener, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener,
                      View.OnClickListener {
...
    public void browser(View view) {
        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
        String test = bundle.getString("Pass the String");


        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com/" + test));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
}
```

On the **CameraActivity** I have created a method **browser** that opens a link when you press the *button*. So, what I want is to use the String from the *MultiboxTracker Activity* so as to search for this specific subject when I press the *button*. I have found various related threads of how to pass a String, but again I am not able to achieve this. I am pretty sure that I am doing something wrong, however I cannot understand where or even if the rationality is wrong.

Here is my last effort using *Intent*:

Pass

```
String test = "White";
Intent i = new Intent(this, CameraActivity.class);
i.putExtra("Pass the String", test);
startActivity(i);
```

Extract

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = i.getExtras();
String test = bundle.getString("Pass the String");
    
// This attempt returns a null value.
```

**Edit:** I am adding my **Logcat**. At this stage, the application performs object detection(prediction) and sequentially I press the created button to search for this prediction. The "W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Aghios Demetrius, Saint Apostoles etc" are **my classes** and by extension the *Strings* I want to pass.

```
2021-03-12 12:01:22.906 22826-22841/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/System: A resource failed to call release. 
2021-03-12 12:01:24.796 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: onStart org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity@27a7313
2021-03-12 12:01:24.798 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: onResume org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity@27a7313
2021-03-12 12:01:24.821 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/CameraMetadataJV: setAppNameAndSensorId org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection, sensorId:0
2021-03-12 12:01:24.821 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/CameraMetadataJV: setAppNameAndSensorId mIsXiaomCam:false
2021-03-12 12:01:24.824 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/CameraMetadataJV: MiAddResolution: 9248x6936, format:33, input:false
2021-03-12 12:01:24.824 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/CameraMetadataJV: MiAddResolution: 9280x6944, format:32, input:false
2021-03-12 12:01:24.831 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Desired size: 640x480, min size: 480x480
2021-03-12 12:01:24.832 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Valid preview sizes: [4640x3472, 4624x3472, 4624x2600, 4624x2136, 3840x2160, 3472x3472, 2560x1920, 1920x1440, 2340x1080, 1920x1080, 1440x1080, 1080x1080, 1440x720, 1280x720, 960x720, 720x480, 640x480]
2021-03-12 12:01:24.832 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Rejected preview sizes: [352x288, 320x240, 176x144]
2021-03-12 12:01:24.832 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Exact size match found.
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Aghios Demetrius
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Saint Apostoles
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Saint Sophia
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Acheiropoietos
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Saint Aikaterini
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Panayia Chalkeon
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Saint Nikolaos Orphanos
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Saint Panteleimon
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Metamorphosis Sotiros
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Profitis Elias
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Osios David
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Vlatadon Monastery
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: White Tower
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Byzantine Baths
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: The Walls
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Trigonion Tower
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Heptapyrgion
2021-03-12 12:01:24.842 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModelWithInterpreter: Rotunda
2021-03-12 12:01:24.931 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Camera orientation relative to screen canvas: 90
2021-03-12 12:01:24.931 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Initializing at size 640x480
2021-03-12 12:01:24.935 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/CameraMetadataJV: setAppNameAndSensorId org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection, sensorId:0
2021-03-12 12:01:24.935 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/CameraMetadataJV: setAppNameAndSensorId mIsXiaomCam:false
2021-03-12 12:01:24.940 22826-22845/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
2021-03-12 12:01:24.941 22826-22845/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
2021-03-12 12:01:24.947 22826-22845/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
2021-03-12 12:01:24.947 22826-22845/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 21
2021-03-12 12:01:24.947 22826-22845/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
2021-03-12 12:01:24.947 22826-22845/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 22
2021-03-12 12:01:24.947 22826-22845/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
2021-03-12 12:01:24.947 22826-22845/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 61
2021-03-12 12:01:24.949 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueueConsumer: [SurfaceTexture-0-22826-0](this:0x7d01237800,id:0,api:4,p:-1,c:22826) setDefaultBufferSize: width=640 height=480
2021-03-12 12:01:24.950 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@9db936c, this = DecorView@af0dd35[DetectorActivity]
2021-03-12 12:01:24.950 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/GraphicExt: GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false
2021-03-12 12:01:24.952 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: CameraConnectionFragment: Opening camera preview: 640x480
2021-03-12 12:01:24.953 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueue: [unnamed-22826-7](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:0,p:-1,c:-1) BufferQueue core=(22826:org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection)
2021-03-12 12:01:24.953 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"
2021-03-12 12:01:24.954 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueueConsumer: [unnamed-22826-7](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:0,p:-1,c:22826) connect(C): consumer=(22826:org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection) controlledByApp=true
2021-03-12 12:01:24.954 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"
2021-03-12 12:01:24.954 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueueConsumer: [unnamed-22826-7](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:0,p:-1,c:22826) setConsumerName: unnamed-22826-7
2021-03-12 12:01:24.954 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.bq.dump"
2021-03-12 12:01:24.954 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueueConsumer: [ImageReader-640x480f23m2-22826-6](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:0,p:-1,c:22826) setConsumerName: ImageReader-640x480f23m2-22826-6
2021-03-12 12:01:24.954 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueueConsumer: [ImageReader-640x480f23m2-22826-6](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:0,p:-1,c:22826) setDefaultBufferSize: width=640 height=480
2021-03-12 12:01:24.954 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/GraphicExt: GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false
2021-03-12 12:01:24.965 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/GraphicExt: GraphicExtModuleLoader::CreateGraphicExtInstance false
2021-03-12 12:01:24.966 22826-22858/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7cf098b000,api=1)
2021-03-12 12:01:24.968 22826-22858/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
2021-03-12 12:01:24.968 22826-22858/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/Surface: Surface::setBufferCount(this=0x7cf098b000,bufferCount=3)
2021-03-12 12:01:24.969 22826-22858/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7cf098b000)
2021-03-12 12:01:24.969 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/TextureView: getHardwareLayer, createNewSurface:false
2021-03-12 12:01:24.969 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/OpenGLRenderer: 0x7cf0ac7b60 setSurfaceTexture: 0x0 to 0x7d01287c00
2021-03-12 12:01:25.053 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-22826-0](this:0x7d01237800,id:0,api:4,p:727,c:22826) connect(P): api=4 producer=(727:???) producerControlledByApp=true
2021-03-12 12:01:25.057 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-640x480f23m2-22826-6](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:4,p:727,c:22826) connect(P): api=4 producer=(727:???) producerControlledByApp=false
2021-03-12 12:01:25.337 22826-22845/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-22826-0](this:0x7d01237800,id:0,api:4,p:727,c:22826) queueBuffer: fps=0.52 dur=7730.43 max=7629.95 min=27.73
2021-03-12 12:01:25.338 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 1061 for detection in bg thread.
2021-03-12 12:01:25.349 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 1061
2021-03-12 12:01:25.376 22826-22858/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/BufferQueueDump: [SurfaceTexture-0-22826-0] [addBuffer] slot(1) acquired, seems to be abnormal, just update ...
2021-03-12 12:01:25.430 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 0 results from 1061
2021-03-12 12:01:25.444 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 1064 for detection in bg thread.
2021-03-12 12:01:25.459 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 1064
2021-03-12 12:01:25.507 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 1 results from 1064
2021-03-12 12:01:25.535 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 1067 for detection in bg thread.
2021-03-12 12:01:25.541 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 1067
2021-03-12 12:01:25.587 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 0 results from 1067
2021-03-12 12:01:25.608 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 1069 for detection in bg thread.
2021-03-12 12:01:25.618 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 1069
2021-03-12 12:01:25.665 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 1 results from 1069
2021-03-12 12:01:25.675 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 1071 for detection in bg thread.
2021-03-12 12:01:25.687 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 1071
2021-03-12 12:01:25.740 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 1 results from 1071
2021-03-12 12:01:25.745 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 1073 for detection in bg thread.
2021-03-12 12:01:25.752 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 1073
2021-03-12 12:01:25.798 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 1 results from 1073
2021-03-12 12:01:25.812 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 1075 for detection in bg thread.
2021-03-12 12:01:25.827 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 1075
2021-03-12 12:01:25.870 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 1 results from 1075
2021-03-12 12:01:25.877 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 1077 for detection in bg thread.
2021-03-12 12:01:25.883 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 1077
2021-03-12 12:01:25.930 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 1 results from 1077
2021-03-12 12:01:25.944 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 1079 for detection in bg thread.
2021-03-12 12:01:25.957 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 1079
2021-03-12 12:01:26.019 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 1 results from 1079
2021-03-12 12:01:26.045 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 1081 for detection in bg thread.
2021-03-12 12:01:26.060 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 1081
2021-03-12 12:01:26.115 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 1 results from 1081
2021-03-12 12:01:26.150 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 1084 for detection in bg thread.
2021-03-12 12:01:26.163 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 1084
2021-03-12 12:01:26.235 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 0 results from 1084
2021-03-12 12:01:26.252 22826-26198/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Preparing image 1087 for detection in bg thread.
2021-03-12 12:01:26.261 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: DetectorActivity: Running detection on image 1087
2021-03-12 12:01:26.280 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:145059470
2021-03-12 12:01:26.350 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-22826-0](this:0x7d01237800,id:0,api:4,p:727,c:22826) queueBuffer: slot 5 is dropped, handle=0x7cf0983580
2021-03-12 12:01:26.350 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-22826-0](this:0x7d01237800,id:0,api:4,p:727,c:22826) queueBuffer: fps=28.62 dur=1013.37 max=53.09 min=17.38
2021-03-12 12:01:26.350 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-640x480f23m2-22826-6](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:4,p:727,c:22826) queueBuffer: fps=28.63 dur=1013.03 max=52.96 min=18.32
2021-03-12 12:01:26.354 22826-26197/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/tensorflow: MultiBoxTracker: Processing 1 results from 1087
2021-03-12 12:01:26.379 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-22826-0](this:0x7d01237800,id:0,api:4,p:727,c:22826) cancelBuffer: slot 7
2021-03-12 12:01:26.379 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-640x480f23m2-22826-6](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:4,p:727,c:22826) cancelBuffer: slot 6
2021-03-12 12:01:26.384 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-22826-0](this:0x7d01237800,id:0,api:4,p:727,c:22826) cancelBuffer: slot 0
2021-03-12 12:01:26.384 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-640x480f23m2-22826-6](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:4,p:727,c:22826) cancelBuffer: slot 0
2021-03-12 12:01:26.385 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-22826-0](this:0x7d01237800,id:0,api:4,p:727,c:22826) cancelBuffer: slot 1
2021-03-12 12:01:26.385 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-640x480f23m2-22826-6](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:4,p:727,c:22826) cancelBuffer: slot 1
2021-03-12 12:01:26.386 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-22826-0](this:0x7d01237800,id:0,api:4,p:727,c:22826) cancelBuffer: slot 2
2021-03-12 12:01:26.386 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-640x480f23m2-22826-6](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:4,p:727,c:22826) cancelBuffer: slot 2
2021-03-12 12:01:26.386 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-22826-0](this:0x7d01237800,id:0,api:4,p:727,c:22826) cancelBuffer: slot 3
2021-03-12 12:01:26.386 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-640x480f23m2-22826-6](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:4,p:727,c:22826) cancelBuffer: slot 3
2021-03-12 12:01:26.392 22826-22841/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
2021-03-12 12:01:26.468 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
2021-03-12 12:01:26.469 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-0-22826-0](this:0x7d01237800,id:0,api:4,p:727,c:22826) disconnect(P): api 4
2021-03-12 12:01:26.469 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
2021-03-12 12:01:26.469 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 21
2021-03-12 12:01:26.469 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueueProducer: [ImageReader-640x480f23m2-22826-6](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:4,p:727,c:22826) disconnect(P): api 4
2021-03-12 12:01:26.469 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
2021-03-12 12:01:26.470 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 22
2021-03-12 12:01:26.470 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
2021-03-12 12:01:26.470 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/CameraManagerGlobal: ignore the torch status update of camera: 61
2021-03-12 12:01:26.473 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/libc: Access denied finding property "camera.aux.packagelist"
2021-03-12 12:01:26.474 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: onPause org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity@27a7313
2021-03-12 12:01:26.880 22826-22858/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7cf098b000,api=1)
2021-03-12 12:01:26.891 22826-22858/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/GED: ged_boost_gpu_freq, level 100, eOrigin 2, final_idx 27, oppidx_max 27, oppidx_min 0
2021-03-12 12:01:26.893 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/tensorflow: CameraActivity: onStop org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity@27a7313
2021-03-12 12:01:26.900 22826-22826/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@9db936c, this = DecorView@af0dd35[DetectorActivity]
2021-03-12 12:01:32.057 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection I/BufferQueue: [ImageReader-640x480f23m2-22826-6](this:0x7cf0d22000,id:7,api:4,p:-1,c:-1) ~BufferQueueCore
2021-03-12 12:01:32.057 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection D/RefBase: RefBase: Explicit destruction, weak count = 0 (in 0x7cf0d23458)
2021-03-12 12:01:32.057 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/RefBase: CallStack::getCurrentInternal not linked, returning null
2021-03-12 12:01:32.057 22826-22843/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/RefBase: CallStack::logStackInternal not linked
2021-03-12 12:01:32.060 22826-22841/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection W/System: A resource failed to call release.
```

Comment: Why did you define your CameraActivity as an abstract class? Please do not make CameraActivity an abstract class and then try to pass using intent, given in the answer below.

Comment: Actually, you may be right, however, the CameraActivity includes various abstract methods, so it is difficult for me to get rid of the abstract. If abstract is my problem then I probably need to create another activity and somehow connect it to the main, don't know! @SanjidChowdhury

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a string like this

```
String test = "white";
Intent intent = new Intent(MultiBoxTracker.this, CameraActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("String", test);
startActivity(intent);
```

And get the string like this

```
intent = getIntent();
String string = intent.getStringExtra("String");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Nonetheless, the outcome is the same (*null*). Considering that the methodology is correct, probably my mistake is from where I am passing the String or something else with the classes that restrict me. @MohammedAbidNafi

Comment: @TechEnth Why don't you paste the logcat once and if possible whole code also I will look into it once.

Comment: I've added my Logcat to my question. Not sure if it is the one you requested or helps. The code contains many Activities, Interphases so it is difficult to upload it here. It is based on the one you can find [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection) from the tensorflow project on github, with some simple alterations. @MohammedAbidNafi

Comment: I dont think that was what I was looking for